# What really is codomain?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, domain-theory

Pretty simple:

Is the codomain of a matrix simply the number of rows, or is it the rank? (The linearly independent rows?)

Maybe I can ask about some examples. [Here are the questions and my answers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy0eX.png)

Comment: In simple terms,no.  Perhaps you are interested in the dimension of the codomain.

Comment: The 'codomain' is neither of those.  It is the [b]subspace[/b] of the range space.  Its [b]dimension[/b] is the rank of the matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your responses. I just added a link to where I'm having problems. If you could take a quick look at the question and explain what the codomain is in this context it would be infinitely appreciated!

Comment: @user247327, no. The codomain is *not* that!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are referring to the codomain when we interpret the matrix as a function, as I am not aware of any other connection between codomains and matrices.

If so, then the dimension of the codomain is given by the *rank* of the matrix, and the codomain itself is the *span* of the linearly independent rows or columns.

Remember that a matrix is just a representation. In this case we use a matrix $M$ to represent a linear function:
$$ M:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R^m.$$
So $M$ sends $a\in \mathbb R^n$ to $M(a)=b\in 
\mathbb R^m$. Practically (and with finite dimensions), this comes down to matrix multiplication: $Ma=b$ or $a^TM=b^T$, depending on whether you represent $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$ with rows or columns.

Now, the codomain is the collection of vectors that are the image under $M$ of some $a\in \mathbb R^n$, that is, it is the collection 
$$\{b\in\mathbb R^m\mid b=M(a) \text{ for some }a\in\mathbb R^n\}.$$

It can be shown that this collection in fact is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$, and that it is spanned by the column- or rowvectors, depending on your choice of representation.